# Delete files when names do not correspond with parts of strings in txt file - Windows batch

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, cmd.exe

There is a txt file, which contains (among many others) strings, which start with:

"HH:MM:SS case"

where H, M, S are hours, minutes and seconds (in 24h format).

There are .jpg files, with names HHMMSS.jpg or HHMMSSxy.jpg (where x, y are digits and/or letters).

How to delete all HHMMSS*.jpg files, which names do NOT correspond with strings "HH:MM:SS case" in .txt file? I can easily find all existing "HH:MM:SS case" strings in .txt file, but do not know, what next.

The dos batch will be used on a XP machine.

P.S. Dear people, I know nothing about scripting. It is not my world. I understand you are not "scripting company" but I hope this is very simple for people, who know the thing.

What I did.

I can find all these strings by: findstr /r /c:"..:..:.. case"

I can put them into another .txt file by adding at the end: > file.txt

I tried few codes with "for" command, but the syntax is too complex for me.

I know how to transform HH:MM:SS into HHMMSS (and make another txt file with these).

I have found some codes to delete files from dir according to a list in txt file.

But I feel this is very crude way.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would move the files you want to keep to a holding directory, then delete the remaining files and move the saved files back. I have no proper idea what the format of your index file is, so I cannot suggest what commands to use, but you will probably need `for /f` with appropriate delimiters and end-of-line characters: this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank You very, very much, due to local time I must quit for now, I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, ' FOR /F "tokens=*" %A IN (file.txt) DO DEL /Q /F "C:\Path\%~A.jpg" ' works, that is it deletes jpg files which are in the txt file.

Now, as I want not to delete these files, but to delete all the others - I think I can change DO DEL to DO MOVE - so I will create a new dir with all the files I want to preserve (as AFH suggested)

Than I can delete all jpgs, and than I can move back preserved files.

If this is correct I think I can handle this.

But is it possible to take first jpg, see if its name first six digits (number) exist on the list, if no - delete, then go to the next etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delete files when names do not correspond with parts of strings in txt**
**file - Windows batch**

> I can find all these strings by: findstr /r /c:"..:..:.. case"
>
> I can put them into another .txt file by adding at the end: > file.txt
>
> I tried few codes with "for" command, but the syntax is too complex
>   for me.

I put together a [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop that uses this `file.txt` with strings you create to iterate through those values of the content of that file to copy the strings *(as file names)* with an appended `.jpg` elsewhere temporarily *(originally it deleted those)*—this is what you confirmed to work and iterate the delete command from my comment suggestions.

**Your comment**

> it deletes jpg files which are in the txt file. Now, as I want not to
>   delete these files, but to delete all the others

The list of strings iterate so I'm not sure how to *easily* add batch script [**IF**](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic and say delete this file *(one-by-one)* if it does not equal **ANY** of the string values from the file name string list *(one-by-one individually wouldn't work here)*—PowerShell would be a different story though I'm sure.

Therefore, the copy to the temp work directory method seems to work well so test it and see how it goes but when I ran it several times, it worked just as expected with the way I have the logic in the example batch script to get the final and expected result as you explained via the original question and your comments afterwards.

Please note that you **WILL NEED** to run this as a `.bat` or `.cmd` file rather than copying and pasting into command prompt manually since the [**CALL**](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command was required with this method.

---

### Batch Script Example

```
@ECHO ON

SET SourcePath=C:\Path
SET WorkPath=C:\Path\TempWork

IF NOT EXIST "%WorkPath%" MD "%WorkPath%"
IF EXIST "%WorkPath%\*.jpg" DEL /Q /F "%WorkPath%\*.jpg"

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN (

    C:\Path\file.txt

) DO (

    CALL :Routine1 "%%~NXA.jpg"

)

DEL /Q /F  "%SourcePath%\*.jpg"
XCOPY /F /Y "%WorkPath%\*.jpg" "%SourcePath%\"
IF EXIST "%WorkPath%\*.jpg" DEL /Q /F "%WorkPath%\*.jpg"
GOTO EOF

:Routine1 
XCOPY /F /Y "%SourcePath%\%~1" "%WorkPath%\"
GOTO EOF
```

**Script Notes/Gotchas:**

- You can use just the file name of the file with the string values (file.txt) or you can use the full path. Just be sure you DO NOT put double quotes around that or it doesn't read the file content values. This may mean that if you use the full path rather than the implicit file name for the `file.txt` then that path including any folder names and the file name **MUST NOT** contain any spaces.
- Be sure the `SET SourcePath=C:\Path` equals a valid file path (with or without spaces here is fine) where the files you want to preserve exist (the source path).
- Be sure the `SET WorkPath=C:\Path\TempWork` equals a valid file path (with or without spaces here is fine) where the files you want to preserve will be copied temporarily until the other files are removed to then be copied back to the original source path.
- You will need to ensure the security context executing this batch script has approciate access to all applicable files and folders to successfully process all the command batch logic operations.

Comment: OK thanks, it works. I did some minor changes. I have to do some more tests to be sure and I will post script back. Thank You for now :) .

Comment: OK, it took some time, but now it works. It is made for right-click on the folder (I did a right-click menus in registery).

Answer (score 0):

OK, it took some time, but now it works. It is made for right-click on the folder (I did a right-click menus in registery).

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET SourcePath=%1
SET WorkPath=%SourcePath%\TempWork

CD /D %SourcePath%

IF NOT EXIST "%WorkPath%" MD "%WorkPath%"
IF EXIST "%WorkPath%\*.bmp" DEL /Q /F "%WorkPath%\*.bmp"
XCOPY /F /Y "%SourcePath%\*mask*.bmp" "%WorkPath%\"


IF EXIST RawList.txt DO DEL RawList.txt
IF EXIST List.txt DO DEL List.txt

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cd') do set foldername=%%~nxA

FINDSTR /r /c:"..:..:.. case"  %foldername%.log > RawList.txt


for /f  "delims=" %%a in (RawList.txt) do (
set str=%%a
set str=!str::=!
set str=!str:~0,6!
echo !str!
) >> List.txt



FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN (

List.txt

) DO (

CALL :Routine1 "%%~NXA*.bmp"

)

DEL /Q /F  "%SourcePath%\*.bmp"

XCOPY /F /Y "%WorkPath%\*.bmp" "%SourcePath%\"
IF EXIST "%WorkPath%\*.bmp" DEL /Q /F "%WorkPath%\*.bmp"

RD /Q /S %WorkPath%

DEL /Q /F RawList.txt
DEL /Q /F List.txt

GOTO :EOF

:Routine1 
XCOPY /F /Y "%SourcePath%\%~1" "%WorkPath%\"
GOTO :EOF
```